# Regex doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, expression, textfield

I am trying to implement a regular expression to allow only one or two digits after a hyphen `'-'` and it doesn't work properly. It allows as many digits as user types after `'-'`

Please suggest my `ExtJS`

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
  hyphenText: "Number and hyphen",
  hyphenMask: /[\d\-]/,
  hyphenRe: /^\d+-\d{1,2}$/,
  hyphen: function(v){
    return Ext.form.VTypes.hyphenRe.test(v);
  }
});

    //Input Field for Issue no
 var <portlet:namespace/>issueNoField = new Ext.form.TextField({
 fieldLabel: 'Issue No',
   width: 120,
   valueField:'IssNo',
   vtype: 'hyphen'

 });
```

This works only to the limit that it allows digits and `-`. But it also has to allow only `1` to `2` digits after `-` at most.

Is something wrong in my regex? `hyphenRe: /^\d+-\d{1,2}$/,`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the regex i suppose. The `hyphenRe` is not at all being called. Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that it expects the input to match exactly with the Regex pattern you have specified. This site [has a zip code example](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010301.htm) that also limits the numbers after the hyphen.

It uses an Else statement to let form function accept one pattern or another pattern option.

The Regex used for the 5-4 format is: "^\d{5}-\d{4}$"

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.form.VTypes.hyphenRe.test(v)` should do the check and not allow the user to enter two `-` at first place.

What you suggest is to check if there is any `-` in field which is totally a different ball game.

The `hyphenRe` is somehow not being called.